# Irregular shading in Graph

Tags: android, user-interface, charts

I tried to replicate a donut chart code that I found in the net. The code is as follows

```
public class DonutChart extends View{

private float radius;
SharedPreferences prefs;
Paint paint;
Paint shadowPaint;
int a,b,c;
Path myPath;
Path shadowPath;

RectF outterCircle;
RectF innerCircle;
RectF shadowRectF;
public DonutChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.DonutChart,
            0, 0
    );

    try {
        radius = a.getDimension(R.styleable.DonutChart_radius, 20.0f);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(radius / 14.0f);

    shadowPaint = new Paint();
    shadowPaint.setColor(0xf0000000);
    shadowPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    shadowPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    shadowPaint.setStrokeWidth(6.0f);
    shadowPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(4, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.SOLID));


    myPath = new Path();
    shadowPath = new Path();


    outterCircle = new RectF();
    innerCircle = new RectF();
    shadowRectF = new RectF();

    float adjust = (.019f*radius);
    shadowRectF.set(adjust, adjust, radius*2-adjust, radius*2-adjust);

    adjust = .038f * radius;
    outterCircle.set(adjust, adjust, radius*2-adjust, radius*2-adjust);

    adjust = .276f * radius;
    innerCircle.set(adjust, adjust, radius * 2 - adjust, radius * 2 - adjust);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // draw shadow

    paint.setShader(null);
    float adjust = (.0095f*radius);
    paint.setShadowLayer(8, adjust, -adjust, 0xaa000000);
    drawDonut(canvas, paint, 0, 359.9f);
    //Orange
    setGradient(0xffEF6632,0xffEF6632);
    drawDonut(canvas,paint, 0,b);
    //Blue
    setGradient(0xff00CCDA,0xff00CCDA);
    drawDonut(canvas, paint, 60,a);
    // blue
//    setGradient(0xff4AB6C1,0xff2182AD);
//    drawDonut(canvas, paint, 120, 60);
    // Grey
    setGradient(0xff557687,0xff557687);
    drawDonut(canvas, paint, 180,c);
}
public void drawDonut(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float start,float sweep){

    myPath.reset();
    myPath.arcTo(outterCircle, start, sweep, false);
    myPath.arcTo(innerCircle, start+sweep, -sweep, false);
    myPath.close();
    canvas.drawPath(myPath, paint);
}

public void setGradient(int sColor, int eColor){
    paint.setShader(new RadialGradient(radius, radius, radius - 5,
            new int[]{sColor, eColor},
            new float[]{.6f, .95f}, TileMode.CLAMP));
}
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int desiredWidth = (int) radius*2;
    int desiredHeight = (int) radius*2;

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int width;
    int height;

    //70dp exact
    if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        width = widthSize;
    }else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        //wrap content
        width = Math.min(desiredWidth, widthSize);
    } else {
        width = desiredWidth;
    }

    //Measure Height
    if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        height = heightSize;
    } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        height = Math.min(desiredHeight, heightSize);
    } else {
        height = desiredHeight;
    }

    //MUST CALL THIS
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
public void getData(int x,int y){
    invalidate();
    a=((x*360)/10);
    b=(y*360)/10;
    c=((10-(x+y))*360)/10;
    String s1,s2,s3;
    s1=String.valueOf(a);
    s2=String.valueOf(b);
    s3=String.valueOf(c);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Inside Chart "+s1+" "+s2+" "+s3 +" "+String.valueOf(x),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

The problem is when I render the graph on my device it gives me a weird shadow like this:

[image: Image 1]

or like this:

[image: Image 2]

What is causing this and how to rectify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually caused because only the value of the line length is changed whereas the starting point is the same so sometimes they tend to overlap.

This can be solved by changing the code as follows

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
super.onDraw(canvas);
// draw shadow
paint.setShader(null);
float adjust = (.0095f*radius);
paint.setShadowLayer(8, adjust, -adjust, 0xaa000000);
drawDonut(canvas, paint, 0, 359.9f);
//Orange
setGradient(0xffEF6632,0xffEF6632);
drawDonut(canvas,paint, 0,b);
//Blue
setGradient(0xff00CCDA,0xff00CCDA);
drawDonut(canvas, paint, b,a);
// Grey
setGradient(0xff557687,0xff557687);
drawDonut(canvas, paint, a+b,c);
}
```